# Error: Unknown authentication strategy "spotify"

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, spotify

I get an error when i try out my code 'Error: Unknown authentication strategy "spotify"'. I even tried googling this issue but can't didn't find an answer

Update: I updated my code to give answers to a person that is helping me

Code

```
const passport = require('passport')
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy
const userWebData = require('../model/userWebSchema')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    const u = user
    done(null, u)
})
passport.deserializeUser(async(spotifyID, done)=> {
    try{
        const data = await userWebData.findOne({ spotifyID: spotifyID})
        const user = data
        return user ? done( null, user) : done(null, null)
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        done(e, null)
    }
})
passport.use(
    new SpotifyStrategy({
        clientID: 'Clients_ID_That_I_Wont_Show',
        clientSecret: 'Clients_Secret_That_I_Wont_Show',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3001/',
        scope: ["user-modify-playback-state", "user-read-private","user-library-read"]
    }, async(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done)=>{
        const userData = await userWebData.findOne({ spotifyID: profile.id})
        if(userData){
            console.log(`User ${profile.displayName} found`)
            return done(err, userData);
        }else{
            let profiles = await userWebData.create(
                {
                    spotifyID: profile.id,
                    spotifyName: profile.displayName,
                    spotifyFollowers: profile.followers,
                }
            )
            profile.save()
            console.log(`New User ${profile.displayName} Created`)
            return done(err, userData);
        }
    }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to import the `passport-spotify` package before authenticating with it. First, install the package (`npm i passport-spotify`) and then require it in your file:

```js
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;
```

Then, you have to call the `passport.use()` function before you can authenticate with `passport`:

```js
passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: client_id,
      clientSecret: client_secret,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8888/auth/spotify/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Finally, you can use it as an Express middleware. Your modified code would look something like:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const passport = require('passport')
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: client_id,
      clientSecret: client_secret,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8888/auth/spotify/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('spotify'), (req, res)=>{
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/user')
}) 
app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    if(req.user == undefined){res.status(401).redirect('http://localhost:3001/')}else{res.send(req.user)}
})

module.exports = app
```

Refer to http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-spotify/

Comment: yea but thats kinda what i have

Comment: Did you install and require the `passport-spotify` library? That's step 1 in making it work.

Comment: yup i did install and require

Comment: Did you call `passport.use` with the proper argument?

Comment: Yes I did that too

Comment: Can you update your answer with your full code?

Comment: Says too add more comments but don't got anything to say

Comment: Can you edit your answer with your current code?